# Route Redirect not Happening when Reducers update State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, reducers

I'm receiving a User model using reducers. The first value is null (because this is how Reducers behave -- it means it's pending and hasn't received the model yet), and the second is the User model itself.

When I get the first null value, the component redirects to the "IsNotSetUp" path, but then when I get the second value, the component shows the isUserSetUp prop as TRUE but it doesn't Redirect to the "IsSetUp" path? What is going on?

[image]

```
class App extends Component {
    state = { isUserSetUp: false }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.auth && nextProps.auth.isProfileSetUp) {
            this.setState({ isUserSetUp: true }, function() {
                console.log("This is when we receive the User model from the reducer");
            });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ isUserSetUp: false });     
        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

                        {/* Profile Set up */}
                        <Route exact path="/setup" render={() => 
                        (
                            this.state.isUserSetUp ? (
                                <Redirect to={'/IsSetUp'} />
                            ) : (
                                <Redirect to={'/IsNotSetUp'} />
                            )
                        )}
                     />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

What's going wrong? What's a workaround? What's a better, suggested path I take?

Thanks in advance, beautifuls ;)

Comment: Are you expecting the component to redirect on rendering `<Redirect />` component?

Comment: Expectation: when the second props comes in, the render() is triggered and the Redirect will push the user to /IsSetUp or /IsNotSetUp accordingly. So yes, when it renders `<Redirect />`, it should redirect. I do not know why it's not. This is the whole code snippet too!

Comment: I think the redirect component will not redirect automatically. It will create a link, on clicking of which it will redirect.

Comment: No, the <Redirect /> doesn't create a link that's exposed to the UI so users can click on it. It's suppose to automatically redirect the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hashHistory` to implement this.

```js
import {
  hashHistory
} from 'react-router';

/**
 * [update route of the application]
 * @param  {String} route [new route of the application]
 */
const updateRoute = (route) => {
  hashHistory.push(route);
};

updateRoute('/IsSetUp');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Nope, no luck. I also want to understand the cause behind my problem -- why doesn't the second value register any Route triggers?